# REGEXP with multiple fields and conditions

Tags: php, regex, mysqli

Instead of searching through a single column for query, I would like my Regexp query to refer to several columns in determining the results of a search as well as limit the the extend of its search activity per session the search function is executed ( so for instance, on the first session the search will only look for the first 10, while if the search is prompted a second time then the next 10 will be sought for). The reason for this limited extend is to prevent latency issues in the long run if the database grows.

I am wanting to do this for a camp roster, where non-fixed keywords will determine the group members of registered campers based on searching through two columns: `hobbies` and `spirit_animal_explanation` for words matching the keywords.

PHP:

```
$searchCD = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE hobbies AND spirit_animal_explanation REGEXP '".$keywords."' LIMIT 10";
$searchST = $con->query($searchCD);

if ($searchST) {
while ($row = $searchST->fetch_assoc()) {

  echo $row["first_name"]. "<br/>" . "<br/>" . $row["hobbies"] . "<br/>" . $row["spirit_animal_explanation"] .
  "<br/>" . $row["avatar"] . "<br/><br/>"  ;

}

}
```

Comment: Full text searching would be best, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html. You could concat those two columns and do a like against it.

Comment: if you want to search in several columns with the same regex and return the row if you find something, then you could probably just concatenate the columns and apply the regex (if not anchored and some other restrictions).

Comment: @chris85 The only thing about full text search that puts me off from using it is that generally it can be very slow for larger databases. But if `LIMIT` clauses can be used in conjunction to full text search queries then I will check it out.

Comment: I haven't had many performance issues with mysql's fulltext, but my tables had < 1 million rows. This thread might be useful though, http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87089/full-text-search-results-in-a-large-amount-of-time-spent-in-fulltext-initializa/87093#87093

Comment: I think adding some sample data with your expected result can make more sense ;).